# How did I get kills without gunship or missile as a commander?

Tags: battlefield-4

I was getting kills without the gunship or missile deployed. All I remember I had deployed was the EMP UAV, and every few seconds, I was hitting a tank and was gaining points right up until I got 100 points, then I got the kill.

How on earth did I kill that poor guy?

**Edit**
It seems that the [EMP UAV](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/EMP_UAV) damages tanks too - but not all the time! Hence why I was so confused yet happy when I killed that guy.

**Update**
I had this happen again over the weekend, but I was on my iPad when it happened - and I can confirm that I had:

- No gunships deployed
- no EMP or UAV deployed
- On Rogue Transmission
- Just captured point C (Gunship point)
- on my iPad

I then lost connection, after the second time it happened, to the server.

Comment: EMP destroys cruise missile and you get 100 points for it. Are you sure you killed someone? Is there was name in killfeed?

Comment: Yeah, I was watching (and didn't want to do anything whilst it was happening) the vehicle getting hit, then when it got to 90 points, the next info I got, was that I had killed a guy and his tank; resulting in 200 points. I didn't see what I had used to do it with.

Comment: I actually just had this happen to me over the weekend.   I had a vehicle destroy and killed someone without gunship or missiles.... not sure how it happened, but I was a-okay with it.

Comment: Hahaha yeah, thats why I didn't do anything and had a big smile on my face while watching it going up. :)

Comment: EMP damages gunships. When you say "without the gunship", do you mean without any or without deploying one yourself? Maybe you destroyed the enemy gunship with an EMP.

Comment: No I didn't deploy a gunship - I could only deploy gunships on that map - it was the radio transmission map

Comment: It is still not clear to me: Was there an enemy gunship in air or not?

Comment: @Kevdog777, I have gotten vehicle kills with the EMP UAV as well.  I think the EMP will do damage to all vehicles in its radius for the duration of its flight.

Comment: I think I just had what you had. Got a kill and don't know how. Weird.

Comment: I've had this happen at least 5-10 times, and I haven't gotten a good answer to it

Comment: what is your source for "It seems that the EMP UAV damages tanks too"

Comment: Well I had the EMP UAV active, but didn't see an enemy gunship anywhere on the map - so I have no idea how I `magically` got a kill and destroyed a vehicle - so I am assuming it is either a bug in the game that it destroys tanks too, or I `magically` got a kill from nowhere?

Comment: Another possible, but unlikely, way to kill as commander: deploy supplie, hit M18 claymore, the claymore hits c4/mine and kills the tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your team captures the control point where an *enemy* gunship is deployed, the gunship will take damage until it gets destroyed.

Are you aboslutely sure you killed a tank with it? I didn't think EMP UAVs damaged tanks...that would be wayyyyyy too easy. I've dropped it over an enemy gunship and that damaged (and killed) the gunship, but I am convinced that EMP UAV does not hurt armor.

Comment: Yip, I did kill an enemy in a vehicle, as I was watching the text, on my screen, `vehicle hit` then after watching a little more, it said `vehicle destroyed 100` and `{username} killed 100` - so maybe it was an enemy gunship that got destroyed, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Since it isn't clear if you mean that you didn't deploy a gunship or if there wasn't any at all, I suggest that you destroyed an enemy gunship with an [EMP UAV](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/EMP_UAV).

Or you dropped a [supply crate](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_Drop) on the head of a poor bastard unlucky enough to stand there:

> The supply drop can also be used to crush inattentive enemies, especially snipers. For this feat, the commander is credited with a generic kill against the victim.

**Edit:** I now had the same thing the OP described and it was no gunship and no supply drop. It really seems like the EMP is also damaging other vehicles. This needs testing and more evidence.

Comment: All I had deployed at that time (that I can remember) is the EMP UAV - I don't even know where the tank was that got destroyed. I didn't drop the supply crate on someone, as the tank blew up and killed the guy.

Comment: Hmm, I missed the "tank" part. Are you sure? What was the kill message?

Comment: It just showed `vehicle hit` about 10 times, then it said `vehicle destroyed` & I killed someone at the same time, hence receiving 200 points.

Comment: I think you're right. Had this as well.

Comment: I think what you mentioned in your answer: `An EMP UAV can be used offensively against an enemy commander's strike assets. A Cruise Missile that flies into the area protected by an EMP UAV will be destroyed in mid-air. Gunships that are patrolling an area will receive gradual damage, even to the point of destruction.` So is the same as what @GarrisonNeely said in the comments below the question.

Answer (score 1):

If an enemy commander deploys a gunship and your team takes back the flag that grants the gunship, the current enemy gunship will take damage out of nowhere until it explodes. If there are still enemies in the gunship when it explodes, the kills are granted to you as commander, even though you did nothing at all.